# Update database using AJAX data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I work in nonrestful environment and can only use ajax request to exchange data. Unfortunately, ajax only recognize POST and GET methods. I need something that sounds like UPDATE in Ajax or PHP to make my app works.

The concept is like this:

I use ajax to receive data that has been created by user, then save it into MySQL with PHP. User can create, edit and save that data. So far I fake it with POST ajax method. But this makes a problem because whenever the user edit and save data, it will keep creating new row in database instead of updating the old one.

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can UPDATE database with basically any of those GET or POST. GET & POST is just method how you passing data to server.

Your php function should handle Update or Create database. You probably need to pass ID and check if ID exist and then Update database.

Edit : Add sample logic

```
<?php
//Assume this is function that your ajax called
function processData()
{
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   $name = $_POST['name'];

   if ($id)
   {
       //Update the name if ID exist
   }
   else 
   {
       //Create new data with Name above
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, you have some reference or guide for that?

Answer (score 0):

you could change your sql? Commonly something along the lines of:-

```
insert into `TABLE` set ( `field1`,`field2` ) values ('value1','value2')
on duplicate key update
 `field1`='value1',
 `field2`='value2',
 `field3`='value3';
```

Sounds like 'update' ?? GET and POST are ideal for what you are trying to do so why reinvent the wheel and come up with a method that doesn't exist?

Comment: but it does exist ... PUT

Comment: yes, PUT is also another method - more suited to uploading files though imho. Take a look at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html - useful info there

Comment: PUT is used extensively in REST methodology